# python component import multi component

Tags: python

I want import

[image]

license.py and profiel.py

```
from scenario.myinfo.license import license
from scenario.myinfo.profile import profile
```

is working but

```
from scenario.myinfo import license, profile
```

is not working
how can I import muilti component

Comment: read about `__init__.py`

Comment: Add `__init__.py` under folder.